# exclude urls or patterns from rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'd like to exclude certain urls from a rule but as I have absolute 0 knowledge about apache I can't seem to nail the conditions.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X_FORWARDED_PROTO} https
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(account|checkout|login) 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/account/login.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index.php?main_page=password_forgotten
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/account/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/account/edit.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/account/address-book/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/account/change-password.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/account/notifications/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php?main_page=checkout&fecaction=null
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php?main_page=checkout_shipping_address
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I believe there should be a way to exclude all urls that contain /account/ or =checkout but i don't know how.

Also can someone please explain what ^ , (.*) , $ are? I think they are operators but I can't seem to find any info and don't have the time to learn apache right now.

Answer (score 0):

All these strange characters are part of regular expressions. See here [`mod_rewrite Introduction- Regular Expressions`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html#regex) for details.

You can omit all of

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/account/login.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/account/edit.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/account/address-book/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/account/change-password.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/account/notifications/
```

because

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/account/
```

already covers all of these.

The test for `=checkout` is different, because this is not part of the URL path, but part of the query string. To exclude every request, which includes `=checkout` in the query string

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.=checkout
```

Comment: thank you very much, unfortunately I think my problem is in the rule somewhere as these modifications do not work, I've also tried to exclude only the index.php but without results.

Comment: @user2173812 Your `RewriteRule` replaces `$1` with `$1`, so this is not surprising. Unless you have other rules, the .htaccess shown is a noop.